# How to detect user selects Don't Allow for MKMapView for iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

I have created a application which uses mapview. For maps I used `MKMapKit` library. Everything works fine when user selects "Allow" button on alert window. But I want to detect when user selects "Don't Allow". I found a delegate which most of the developers used

`(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error`

but the delegate does not get called.

Maybe I am missing something. In my header (.h) file I have implemented `MKMapViewDelegate`. Is there anything else I need to do?

Do I need to add some extra classes like `CLLocationManager` or else.

Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to monitor the changes in the authorization status for the location services you need to implement the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` obtaining something like

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        // permission denied
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
        // permission granted
    }
}
```

For a complete list of the possible authorization statuses and their description you can check out the official documentation of [CLAuthorizationStatus](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html).

**EDIT**

You probably have already your instance of `CLLocationManager`, let's call it `locationManager`. Then in order to implement your delegate you conform your class to the `CLLocationManagerDelegate` protocol (you can declare it in the header of class -- this is not mandatory but it will provide you some static checking facilities) and assign it to the `delegate` property of `locationManager` like follows:

```
locationManager.delegate = self; //assuming that self is gonna be the delegate
```

If you did everything as explained your controller will be called at every authorization change, as stated by the documentation:

> this method is called whenever the application’s ability to use location services changes.

Comment: but the issue is delegate does not get called. Do I need to implement CLLocationManagerDelegate in header class? What after I include it? Can you provide me steps?

Comment: I have done this. But no effect. Delegate does not get called. I just want to detect when user selects don't allow option on alert view.

Comment: that's very weird. Why don't you update your question with the actual code you're using to initialize the location manager

Comment: Hoho that was my mistake. I forgot to initialize location manager. What a stupidity I done. Thanks to all of you.

Comment: I'm glad that you fixed that.

Comment: Without using location manager, can't we identify using MKMapkit framework itself?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this:

```
if(![CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    // alert location services denied
}
```

Comment: this will tell you whether location services are enable globally on the system, not for this particular application. Location services may be enabled globally but not for this particular application. Moreover it does not update you when the state changes.

Comment: location service is enabled.

Comment: this option decides whether location service is enabled or not. thanks to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
// in appdelegate put thecode

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
     {
        //location denied, handle accordingly
         NSLog(@"Dont allow");

    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
    {
        NSLog(@"Allow");
        //hooray! begin startTracking
    }

}
```

// Wheneever you check

```
- (IBAction)showMapBtnPressed:(id)sender {

    if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied)
    {
        NSLog(@"Dont allow");

    }else
    {
        NSLog(@" allow");
    }


}
```